# How to fix setState after setTimeout

Tags: reactjs

I wanna make loop timer like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sSsn.jpg,
But after dropping my timer freezes for 3 sec (like timeout time)

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { start, end } = this.state;

    this._loop = setInterval(this.counter, 60)
}

counter = () => {
    const { startNumber, endNumber } = this.props;
    const { start, end } = this.state;

    if (start <= endNumber) {

        this.setState({start: this.state.start + 150})            
    } else {
        this.timerInterval = setTimeout( () => {
            this.setState({start: startNumber})
        }, 1000);
    }
}

timerInterval = null;
_loop = null;
```

maybe counter method wrote wrong ?? 
And I did not found any similar examples, only with control buttons
If you have some references please share with me
Thanks..

here my full code https://codepen.io/liashok/pen/OYOKyZ

Comment: setState is an asynchronous function...it might be that what is causing the issue? Especially with timings involved. Have you tried doing the following or similar..this.setState(function(state, props) {return {start: state.start +150}})

Comment: no, I didn't.  I'll try

Comment: the same result =(